# JavaEE, PrimeFaces, some sort of "h:link" validation

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm sorry for that basic question, but I'm in kinda trouble here...
I've got following treeTable:

```
<p:treeTable id="tree" value="#{things.allThings}" var="item">
    <!-- some <p:column> and stuff -->
    <!-- now the important one -->
    <p:column>
        <h:link id="stuff" outcome="stuffList" value="Stuff">
             <f:param name="type" value="things"/>
             <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}"/>
        </h:link>
    </p:column>
```

What I need, is to hide the link if `#{item.id} != "5"` for example.
Or a some sort of validation like `show h:link only if #{item.id} == "5"`

Does there exist a tag for h:link or something simelar to realize it?

Thx very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rendered` attribute for `<h:link>`

Example

```
<h:link id="stuff" outcome="stuffList" value="Stuff" rendered="#{item.id ne 5}"/>
```